# python os.rename returns [Error 5] Access is denied on windows server 2012 sometimes

Tags: python, windows, windows-server-2012

we have python script which will rename the folder at run time and this script invoked as network service account.

We are getting [Error 5] Access denied error sometimes(not all the times). so the script getting failed to complete the task.

Comment: Did you check your rights on the directory you want to rename?

Comment: Yes... this error coming sometimes only not all the time

Answer (score 0):

I don't like "sometimes", you should look for "in some cases". For example maybe some folders do not have the right permission settings, of maybe "rename" somehow changes them. Maybe some names are not right. For example Windows does not allow for specific characters, a path name greater than 260 characters, etc.

Here is [a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) referencing) the limitations of the Windows naming convention for path names. Maybe make sure the path you indicate is of type Unicode, which can help in case you have special characters in between (as Windows uses CP-1252 and not UTF-8 for characters encoding).

If this is not sufficient, please provide more examples.